# Log a user in manually, get session?

Tags: 8

A service I have takes a username, and should find and log in a local Drupal user account with that username. After logging in, I need the session ID (from the sessions table) for that users new session.

I have some basic procedural code that I'd like to refactor for Drupal 8 practices:

```
$user = user_load_by_name($username);
if ($user) {
  user_login_finalize($user);
}
```

1) What's the OO way of loading a user entity? A service I found that may help loading a user is `entity.manager`, but is that the right way to do it?

2) Logging a user in? Should I just take the code from `user_login_finalize` and try and inject the services used and essentially "copy" what's done in that function?

3) After the user is logged in, how can I get their session information? Injecting the `current_user` service doesn't work, because the user data in there is stale after I log the user in.

**EDIT**: Looks like a user's session is not saved until `AuthenticationSubscriber` runs (listens for kernel response event), which is when the session data would be saved. Maybe I can manually save the session before then, and then obtain session? Not sure what that would impact.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem and can't find a solution, so I was wondering a) if either you managed to resolve it, and b) if not, do you think waiting for a `KernelEvents::REQUEST` and then doing something with the session is secure?

Comment: Core's user_login_finalize stores the session right away now. So you can extract it from the session service immediately after calling that function. I asked this question when working on a D8 port of the CAS module. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/cas/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Service/CasUserManager.php#L234

Answer (score 1):

1. For general entity, yes you can use [entity.manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityManager.php/class/EntityManager/8) service.

   For user entity, you can use [\Drupal\user\Entity\User](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8). However in your case, you are going to load user by username, this can't be done by User Entity class, you have to use `entity.manager`.

   `user_load_by_name` will call something like this:

   ```
   $entity_manager = Drupal::service('entity.manager');
   $user = $entity_manager->storage('user')->loadByProperties(array('name' => $nusername));
   ```
2. I will just use this function if there is no reason to replace it.
3. Use the [session_manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21SessionManager.php/class/SessionManager/8) service.

   ```
   $session_manager = Drupal::service('session_manager');
   $session_id = $session_manager->getId();
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `session_manager` because the it seems the session for the newly logged in user isn't persisted until `AuthenticationSubscriber` runs (see my edit)