# Programmatically User login not working

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to login users programmatically in Drupal 8. Here goes my code:

```
if(isset($uid)) {
  $user = User::load($uid);
  user_login_finalize($user);
  $user_destination = \Drupal::destination()->get();
  $response = new RedirectResponse($user_destination);
  $response->send();
  exit(0);
}
```

I am getting the message 'Session opened for...' in watchdog. But the user is not logged in. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you confirm your domain got the dot (`.`)? And your `$base_url` is set correctly or unset in the settings file?

Comment: Can you check if that helps: [Log a user in manually, get session](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/131063/1908).

Comment: The default auth is done via cookies(session) so probably the code is blocking the setcookie or something(the redirect response).

Comment: Get rid of the exit

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, did you find the solution? @romisha-aggarwal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your code is Ok.

just add the following namespace:

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

delete in your code:

```
 user_login_finalize($user);
```

and

```
 exit(0);
```

A complete example would be.

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$uid=1;

if(isset($uid)) {
  $user = User::load($uid);
  user_login_finalize($user);
  $user_destination = \Drupal::destination()->get();
  $response = new RedirectResponse($user_destination);
  $response->send();
ksm($user);
}
```

if you have installed the

> devel

module and the

> Kint

submodule,
You can use the function

> ksm()

, to show the information of a variable.

Comment: Hey Jhonatan, why delete user_login_finalize, when then in your complete example again adding it?

Comment: use XDebug instead devel

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code that you can paste into a new file and run

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

// ID of the user.
// REPLACE WITH WHATEVER ID YOU WANT TO LOGIN AS;
$uid = 100; 
$user = Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);

// This is required to call user_login_finalize here.
$kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
user_login_finalize($user);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Ref: http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/76/login-programmatically-as-a-user