# Login user programatically (Create user session)

Tags: users

My question is based on this question: [Programmatically User login not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250597/programmatically-user-login-not-working) i dont have this clear, to login an user (create an active session) only need use User::Load()? i'm triying make this on my custom module, due to i need an independent login and register form, but dont work. Someone can help me? i want create a user session and let the user navigate for all sections that your role have assigned, but without pass by "user/login" route. Thanks in advance. On resume i want emulate the login controller shipped with drupal 8.

Comment: User::load() loads information about an account, it does not inject or alter the current session in any way. `user_login_finalize()` is one of the key functions.

Comment: Ok, how i can create a session for an user programatically? can you help me?

Comment: Ohh!!! ok, i get it, user_login_finalize() open a session for the provided user. Thanksa a lot!!! :D. Please put the comment in an answer for select as the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically User login not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250597/programmatically-user-login-not-working)

Comment: Is the same article that i refer on my question, but for novices as me, is not obvious the response in the related topic, due to acepted response says: Delete user_login_finalize($user); and this line of code is just the line that log an user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User::load()` loads information about an account, it does not inject or alter the current session in any way. `user_login_finalize()` is one of the key functions when doing programatic user logins because it will create and set a session for the current user.

See more:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_finalize/8.7.x

Comment: Sorry, forgot to link to it. Updated.